# My site link dissappeared from search results after the link building started

Tags: seo, google

I have a site named keralatourmate.com. While searching One of the important keyword "kerala honeymoon packages from bangalore", it dissappeared.
Actually it was on the 4th page till yesterday.We started directory submission for this particular keyword 3 days before only. Please tell whther this is a negative effect of directory submission or some other factors.